# Adding a BackgroundTint on a ToggleButton messes the Background itself

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-button, togglebutton

I have a layout with multiple `ToggleButtons` with a custom layout. Each of them must have a different color.

[image]

To achieve that I've created a selector with 2 items in it for the checked and unchecked state. The cheked item has a drawable inside. So I have the xml's like this:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/color_picker_btn_1"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_color"/>
```

The selector_button_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle"/>
</selector>
```

The shape_circle_checked:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"
        android:visible="true">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check">
  </item>
```

The problem is that when I apply a background tint on the `ToggleButton` I can't see the drawable on the Checked state.

[image: Buttons without and with background tint (both checked)]

I would like to know if there is a way to select the background color of each `ToggleButton` without messing up the background itself with the drawable. Otherwise I will have to create a custom background for every single `ToggleButton`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess the background tint is coloring both the oval shape and the tick at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I created an SVG with the circle and the check. That does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/toogleButtton1"
    style="@style/circleButton.Green"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/toogleButtton2"
    style="@style/circleButton.Red"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/toogleButtton3"
    style="@style/circleButton"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />
```

with:

```
<style name="circleButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/circle</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_add_24px</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/custom_button_icontint_selector</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:checkable">true</item>
</style>

<style name="circleButton.Green">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Green</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Green" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green500</item>
</style>

<style name="circleButton.Red">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Red</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Red" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red600</item>
</style>

<!-- Circular ShapeAppearance -->
<style name="circle">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>

<!-- custom selector for icon tint to hide the icon when unchecked -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

[image]